# Unable to send emails in Django

Tags: django, email, smtp, cpanel

I've created an email account in the cPanel of my website and want to use it to send emails using the Django web framework.

There are the configurations in my Django settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.mydomain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

but when I run the function of ending the email I get this error:

```
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

So, what I've missed and occurred this problem.

Comment: Do you use some real email service or have you just entered values randomly?

Comment: @NixonSparrow Yes, I am using real values.

Comment: Where did you get that value from? It seems that `EMAIL_HOST` is not correct.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to show the domain here, so I wrote 'mydomain' but it's an actual domain in the code.@NixonSparrow

Comment: Have you tried `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`?
If it works, it's most certain something with your `EMAIL_HOST`.

Comment: @NixonSparrow Yes it's worked with `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`